# Activity Dialog with black screen around

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I have a problem with closing my Activity. I'm want to start activity by alarm. I've done that alarm start my activity, but I want to make it a dialog, so I set theme of that activity to android:Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar but I looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlfx1.png

I've also tried adding:

```
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Translucent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

But I makes transparent not elements that I want to, it looks like that

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfvDL.png

Is there way to fix this, or do you have any diferent ideas to make this heppen.
Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Comment: No, I did not. I left this project. But if you have a solution, I would be glad to hear.

Comment: I did it without using activity. 
var mAlertDialog = new `Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.This).SetMessage("sdfsdf").Create();          mAlertDialog.Window.SetType(Android.Views.WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert);
mAlertDialog.Show();`
And set `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission